# Будет ли определение входить в основу?

Tags: сказуемые

> Культура - ёмкое понятие!
> Должно ли "ёмкое" входить в состав сказуемого?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148170/discussion-on-question-by--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ однозначен: ***"емкое"*** может быть только определением в данном случае.
Значение существительного (в том числе слова "понятие") может иногда ослабляться, и чаще всего это бывает при инверсии.
Сравните:

> *Холодная* осень. Осень **холодная**

В первом предложении "холодная" будет определением, во втором - сказуемым.

> Достаточно посмотреть, как Розенталь выделяет сказуемые в предложениях
> такого типа: Двадцать лет — хорошая **вещь** (Сим.)

Когда же прилагательное встает после существительного, его значение ослабляется, и акцент переносится на прилагательное.

> Иногда название признака, обозначенного в сказуемом, присоединяется к
> подлежащему при помощи слов человек, мужчина, женщина, народ,
> животное, вещь и т.п., употребленных с ослабленным лексическим
> значением, например: Вы **человек добрый**;
> Родители Валентины Михайловны **были** **люди небогатые** (Т.); А ведь
> обед - **вещь приятная** (Черн.); **Народ** вы **проезжий** (Ч.).

---

Таким образом, культура - емкое **понятие**, но культура - **понятие емкое**.
Такой же позиции придерживаются эксперты ФИПИ.

---

Благодарю вас, автор, за то, что приняли **единственно возможный правильный вариант, - мой вариант**. Не надо покупаться на бредни недалеких лингвистов, не умеющих работать с текстом.
Ответы, данные на Лингвофорумах, ключи, приложенные к заданиям ВПР, опыт, полученный из комментариев специалистов, отвечающих на вопросы школьников, - всё это говорит о правильности выбора:

> 1. https://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=58268.0 [Форум. Ответы от разбирающихся в вопросе людей]

**Вопрос:**
Он хороший человек, добрый. Почему тут запятая? "Хороший" и "добрый" - однородные члены? И вообще - как это надлежит разобрать с точки зрения синтаксиса?

---

**Ответ:**

-Обособленное **определение**, которое носит характер уточнения/пояснения.

-Однородные **определения** — запятая нужна.

> 2.https://otvet.mail.ru/question/209433567 [Вопрос ученика. Ответ от квалифицированного филолога]

**Вопрос:**
Расставьте знаки препинания — Он великий человек сэр. — Больше чем великий. Он хороший человек.

---

**Ответ:**

В первой реплике и во втором предложении второй реплики тире не нужны, так как подлежащие выражены личным местоимением ОН, а сказуемые – существительным ЧЕЛОВЕК.

> 3.https://rus6-vpr.sdamgia.ru/test?theme=7 [Самый популярный сайт для подготовки к экзаменам]

-Нас интересует выделяемая основа: *"Риск - благородное **дело**" [жирным выделено сказуемое]

-Нас интересует выделяемая основа: "Весна - самое прекрасное **время**" [жирным выделено сказуемое]

---

Всегда проверяйте, кто вам дает ответ, - специалист или дилетант.

---

**Ответ от специалиста "Грамоты.ру".**

1)В современной лингвистике данный вопрос признается ***дискуссионным***. При инверсии существительное **десемантиризуется**, что позволяет говорить о расширении состава сказуемого. При прямом порядке слов значение существительного тоже может **десемантизироваться**, однако четких "границ", показывающих, что слово потеряло свое значение, не имеется. Академическая грамматика данный вопрос практически не освещает. Литневская разбирает примеры такого типа: "ОН лучший **ученик** из класса". Для того, чтобы убедиться в том, что слово потеряло значение, можно попробовать **исключить** его из предложения: "Он *лучший из класса*". Однако данный метод не позволяет однозначно решить вопрос с похожими сочетаниями. Например,  "он хороший человек": он хороший, он человек? В зависимости от того, является лингвист **формалистом** или *семантиком*, возможны различные варианты ответов.

2)В школьной грамматике данный вопрос решается **однозначно**. Что не является фразеологизированным сочетанием, не входит в список слов в определенным значением (избирательность, метафоричность, "количественность", неопределенность, определенность, контекстуальная цельность), разбирается **формально**, поэтому "он хороший **человек**", "культура - емкое **понятие**".

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а вы используете понятие "свободные и несвободные сочетания"? Ведь для этого вопроса существует теория со своими определениями и выводами, дается перечень несвободных сочетаний.

Comment: @ShAron Критика запрещена на этом сайте. Если у вас другое мнение, вы можете написать свой ответ. Автор сам решит, какое решение является ПРАВИЛЬНЫМ.

Comment: Ладно, про тире убираю. Оставлю только уточняющий вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Sharon Комментарии запрещены. Не нарушайте правила форума. Ваш ответ неверен в корне. Вы можете считать что угодно, однако ваш бред читают школьники, и они могут сделать вывод, что так и правда правильно.

Comment: @Sharon Ваше мнение можете оставить при себе: оно мне неинтересно. Вы — копия oleeed.

Comment: Мой ответ неверен? Докажите, что это так.

Comment: @Sharon Прочитайте еще раз мой ответ: порядок слов все решает. У Розенталя говорится тоже об этом: сочетание девочка добрая, с ослабленным лексическим значением существительного девочка. Ср. аналогичные примеры: Старушки все народ сердитый (Грибоедов); Вы человек добрый, вы честный человек (Тургенев); Родители Валентины Михайловны были люди небогатые (он же); Притом пес — животное умное (он же); А ведь обед — вещь приятная (Чернышевский).

Comment: @sharon Если бы он считал так, как вы, он бы так написал: "Вера - добрая девочка" - и  разбирал бы он именно такой пример, но он использовал инверсию, и во всех примерах использована инверсия.

Comment: Та же логика относится и к безличным односоставным и полным двусоставным предложениям, которые вы тоже неверно разбираете: печально видеть голую степь (сказуемое "печально видеть"), видеть голую степь печально (сказуемое "печально", подлежащее "видеть"). Порядок слов многое решает.

Comment: @Ajgy, вы специалист?

Comment: @Серж почему вы правила форума нарушаете? Комментарии комментариев запрещены.

Comment: Я задал вам вопрос. Вы первым нарушаете правила, давая субъективную оценку. И причем не лесную.

Comment: @Серж А вы за собой следите, а не за мной.

Comment: Да? А я не вешаю ярлыки.

Comment: @Серж Отлично. Только мне ваше мнение неинтересно от слова СОВСЕМ.

Comment: Вот и весь ответ. В школьной(!)программе. В академической среде вопрос дискуссионный, о чем говорили и мы.

Answer (score 2):

Да, это слово входит в состав сказуемого. *Ëмкое* — это самое главное слово в этом сказуемом, без него смысл будет совсем не тот.

Comment: Вот зачем минусовать ответ без указания причины. Минусовка - это признание своего неумения дать внятное объяснение, последний довод, когда слов не хватает. Что тут неверного? Решение указано, объяснение дано.

Comment: Вопрос сложный, голосование решает многое. И тем более некорректна эта АНОНИМНАЯ минусовка. Я тоже могу снять голос за ответ, которым недовольна. Но я не делаю этого! Другие же участники считают это нормальным: дать свой ответ и заодно ЗАМИНУСОВАТЬ оппонента. Чем плохо обозначить свое мнение ДВА РАЗА.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Лично я не стремлюсь к получению галочки и отвечая не ради репутации, а просто чтобы помочь другим разобраться в этом. Поэтому минусовать мне якобы конкурентов нет смысла.

Comment: Тут дело не только в репутации. Минус снимет всего два балла, это немного. Но знак влияет на общее мнение: вот принятый ответ с двумя-тремя  голосами, он правильный. А этот ответ минусовали, значит, он неверный. Минусовка оппонента — нечестный прием. Мы не видим, кто минусует и считаем, что это мнение всей аудитории. Я никогда не ставлю минусы. Но часто убираю чужие положительным голосованием. Двое проголосовали против вас, двое за вас, а в результате у вас нет голосов.

Comment: Ваш ответ верен по сути, но доказать его не так просто. Здесь надо учитывать ситуацию общения (коммуникативность). Вот скажите кому-нибудь: "Культура – понятие", а потом молчите. Что о вас подумает собеседник?  Скажет: «Америку открыл!»  Потому что нет в этом сообщении информации, если только вы не беседуете на очень философские темы.

Answer (score 2):

Это тема **свободных и несвободных сочетаний**. Слово понятие  можно отнести к словам с отвлеченным значением **[Современный синтаксис, стр 6 - 9](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)**

В этом случае возможны **контекстуально несвободные сочетания**. Это означает, что семантическая недостаточность  зависит **от контекста**: о чем говорят собеседники. Такие сочетания могут быть как свободными, так и несвободными.

Вариант 1.  ***Культура — понятие.** Не надо смешивать понятие  с предметом. Понятие – это форма мышления, а предмет – некоторая целостность, выделенная из мира объектов в процессе деятельности и познания.*

Здесь ***понятие*** является самодостаточным словом, играет роль сказуемого и может использоваться без распространителя.

Вариант 2. ***Культура — емкое понятие**. Она может включать в себя все, то создано человеческим трудом, а не только то, что относится к духовной жизни.*

Здесь уже фраза имеет смысл при наличии **определения,** которое нужно включить в состав сказуемого. Без распространителя  не обойтись,  ведь речь идет именно о емкости понятия. То, что культура относится к понятию, его собеседник и так знает.

**ВЫВОД**

Второй вариант представляется более **демократичным и вероятным**. Первый варант используется в разговоре на чисто **философские** темы.

**Приложение (материал из комментариев)**

Скажите, пожалуйста, а вы используете понятие "свободные и несвободные сочетания"? Для этого вопроса существует теория со своими определениями и выводами, дается перечень несвободных сочетаний. Тире же в предложении ставится между группой подлежащего и группой сказуемого, но туда входят и зависимые слова тоже. Поэтому **тире не определяет грамматический состав сказуемого.** –

Хорошо, у вас здесь классическая схема: подлежащее, сказуемое, определение. Определение не входит в сказуемое. Теперь-то правильно? Так решается задача **по обычному стандарту**,  и мало у кого такое решение вызывает сомнение: **ученик 3-го класса** и тот без труда определит все члены предложения. Но зачем же автор задает такой "странный" вопрос? Вероятно, это уже программа **старшеклассников и выпускников.** "Завалить" ведь могут на экзамене.

Но уж лучше решать задачу по правилам **3-го класса,** чем ориентироваться на справочник Розенталя в теме «**тире между подлежащим и сказуемым»**. Тогда уж точно экзамена не сдать.

Answer (score 2):

**Комментарий к ответу**

**Интересные** предложения приведены во второй части ответа, но каждое из них индивидуально и требует **особого разбора**. В ответе же они собраны воедино для доказательства еще одного индивидуального предложения. Вот что **не есть хорошо.**

Это мое впечатление от прочтения. Любое из приведенных предложений  может быть **темой отдельного обсуждения** и имеет свое решение. Но я, пожалуй, остановлюсь **на одном** (из Лигвофорума, 2013 год) и задам по нему вопрос на нашем форуме.

**Знакомый ресурс** — и мой первый опыт в сетевом пространстве. Может, и профиль сохранился (правда, незашифрованный). Да и участники 2013 года мне знакомы, разговаривала с ними. Обычные люди, как и мы, отнюдь не небожители. Так что можно обсудить их ответы.

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474954/Он-хороший-человек-добрый-Уточнение-или-однородные-отношения](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474954/%D0%9E%D0%BD-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 01.09.2023**

Цитирую автора ответа:

*Благодарю вас, автор, за то, что приняли **единственно возможный правильный вариант**, - мой вариант. Не надо покупаться **на бредни недалеких лингвистов, не умеющих работать с текстом.** Ответы, данные на Лингвофорумах, ключи, приложенные **к заданиям ВПР**, опыт, полученный из комментариев специалистов, отвечающих на вопросы **школьников,** - всё это говорит о правильности выбора... Всегда проверяйте, кто вам дает ответ, - специалист или **дилетант**.*

Кто же здесь недалекий специалист, не умеющий работать с текстом, а также дилетант? Это я или все участники форума? Я действительно предпочитаю **семантический метод анализ** как более современный и продвинутый, в отличие от формального, рекомендованного в школе.

Термин "**контекстуальная целостность**" мне тоже знаком. Он знаком сейчас очень многим, обсуждается на других форумах. Вот пример по данной теме: **Свободные и несвободные сочетания** https://rusforus.ru/viewtopic.php?t=12675

Наш сайт — это форум **лингвистов и энтузиастов русского языка**, а не форум для решения домашних заданий и ответов **по школьной программе.** Поэтому не стоит автору считать свой ответ единственно правильным.

Comment: Споря с моим утверждением, вы спорите с Розенталем, Потихой и Ивановой.

Comment: ОН хороший человек - здесь еще как-то можно попытаться отыскать неделимое сочетание. НО в "культура  - емкое понятие" - тут вопросов быть не может: оба слова имеют свое конкретное значение, сочетание свободное.

Comment: А зачем вы привели этот пример в ответе? Неудачный выбор? (Я могу и другие ваши примеры рассмотреть, если будет нужно.)  И зачем теперь вы сравниваете и что-то доказываете. Ваш единственно правильный ответ уже принят, все ваши доказательства вы уже обозначили.  Этого не может быть, потому что не может быть никогда. Поэтому спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Потому что вам не дает покоя это, раз вы даже создали новый вопрос.

Comment: А там тема хорошая, и знакомых вот вспомнила. Мне там Марго нравилась, я за нее в той теме. Попробуйте ответить, сравните свои возможности с теми участниками. Может, мы лучше их ответим, убедительнее.  Соревнование.

Comment: Хорошо бы было, если б вы и неправоту свою  признали.

Comment: Только если пытать будете))  Я не герой, все признаю)

Comment: Я не увидел у вас ни одного доказательства. На что вы ссылаетесь - ни на что!

Comment: Ладно, пока. Ничего нового я от вс не услышу.  Тут дело не в самом факте (всегда входит, никогда не входит или иногда входит). Дело в методе доказательства. А метод известен - анализ сочетания, свободное или несвободное. Методику в книге посмотрите. Докажите вашу правоту этим методом. Но это вам ДЗ,  а сейчас до свидания. Здесь не разрешено разговаривать.

Comment: Вам уже было сказано, что связанным оно будет в постпозиции.

Comment: Мне анализ нужен по всем правилам. В книге посмотрите, там дан список и указаны принципы. А про постпозицию я все знаю, от нее зависит расстановка логических ударений, только зачем все это. Это в других темах можно применить, но не здесь.

Comment: Ладно. Вас не убедить. Вы не слышите аргументов.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, потому что это вообще не сказуемое. Это реверсивная конструкция, которая разрывает сложное подлежащее.

Прямая фраза звучик как:

Понятие "культура" - ёмкое.

Ёмкое понятие "культура".

Красивое имя Иван => Иван - красивое имя.

То есть подлежащее *понятие "культура"*, сказуемого нет, *ёмкое* - определение.

А вот предложение: культура понятие ёмкое, - не требует тире, потому что *культура понимается ёмко*, вот тут уже *культура* - подлежащее, *понятие/понимается* - сказуемое, *ёмкое/ёмко* - предикация в составе сказуемого. То есть реверс определения относительно определяемого слова создает предикацию. С другое стороны зачем тут тире, если это предикация к сказуемому?

А вот фраза с тире: культура - понятие ёмкое, - выглядит уже сомнительно, как скорее уравнивание двух несвязанных понятий. Вроде: кошка - мыши тихие. Что хотят сказать такой фразой сложно сказать, что-то вроде: когда кошка охотся, все мыши сидят тихо. Вот только как построить такое рассуждение из "культура - понятие ёмкое", я не знаю. Хотя даже с кошкой криво, нормально было бы если: кошка в дома - мыши тихие.

То есть с тире еще можно составить фразу: русская культура - понятие ёмкое. В моём понимании только так звучит, потому что культура - это просто термин, у терминов нет характеристик внутри таксономии.

Вообще есть такой момент, что культура - это такое себе существительное, потому что это от слова культурный, то есть от прилагательного. В общем: Иван - имя красивое, - звучит, а вот с культурой не звучит, совсем. Возможно потому что Иван, это не только имя, это может быть сам человек, может быть кличка животного, и тд, а культура - это только понятие, а точнее термин, по-другому никак. А то получается, что это какая-то культура, в смысле агрокультура что ли.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148192/discussion-on-answer-by-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Не могу разобраться в том, что написано)))))но спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Современная лингвистическая наука при определении синтаксической роли слова требует обязательного учёта **семантики** не только слова в словосочетании, но и предложения в целом, а в некоторых особенно трудных случаях и даже целого текста. Недаром член предложения в лингвистической литературе определяется как **структурно-семантическое образование**, в котором семантика каждого слова должна обязательно учитываться.

Так, Фёдоров А.К. в своей книге «Трудные вопросы синтаксиса» пишет: «Члены предложения выделяются на основе **структурно-семантического принципа**, поскольку структура предложения рассматривается **в единстве** с семантикой, которую приобретает данная структура и её компоненты в речи».

Бабайцева В.В. в своей монографии «Система членов предложения в современном русском языке» при определении синтаксической роли слова в предложении также указывает на обязательность семантической составляющей: «Если основной смысл заключён в зависимом слове, а структурную функцию выполняет главное слово, то такое словосочетание входит в состав одного члена предложения».

В рассматриваемой структуре слово «понятие» семантически не несёт абсолютно никакой смысловой нагрузки, вне зависимости от того, в пре или пост позиции к нему расположено прилагательное «ёмкое», оно выполнят лишь роль опоры в структуре. Тогда как весь смысл предложения заключён именно в слове «ёмкое». Именно слово «ёмкое» является центром предикативного признака в структуре предложения «культура – ёмкое понятие». Говорящий не ставит своей целью убедить нас, что культура – это понятие, он утверждает, что оно ёмко.

Таким образом, слово «ёмкое» - семантически необходимый распространитель слова «понятие» в конкретной логической структуре. Оно является сематическим ядром предикативного признака и, следовательно, входит в состав сказуемого.

Comment: Согласен с вами!

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ,  все очень интересно. И у меня к вам вопросы. Кто из современных лингвистов поддерживает и продолжает учение Федорова? Вы знаете какие-нибудь новые монографии по сложным предложениям, в том числе СПП? У меня есть новые книги о простом и осложненном предложении, а по сложным ничего нового нет.

Comment: @Sharon я могу поделиться с вами ссылкой на свою папку в Google Диске и вы сами сможете поискать там то, что было бы вам полезно.)

Comment: Да, спасибо, это было бы хорошо. А я смогу найти там нужную тему,  это не трудно?

Comment: Там всё очень просто. Кстати, стоило потрудиться, чтобы всё это скачать.)

Answer (score 0):

**Дополнение к ответу от 23.10.2023**

Да, семантика в современной грамматике очень важна, и существует такое понятие, как **семантический синтаксис**.

Предложение можно рассматривать **как единицу языка.** Это основные структурные схемы и составленные на их основе **модели предложений.** Об этом в частности говорится в книге В. И. Казариной **«Простое предложение в аспекте структурно-семантического подхода» (2019).**

Но предложение можно рассматривать и как **единицу речи**  — это **использование** говорящим  определенной модели предложения с нужным лексическим наполнением .

***Культура — ёмкое понятие!***

Я представляю это так.

Существует модель предложения **из трех компонентов**: подлежащее (субъект), сказуемое (предикат) и определение, отнесенное к субъекту. Но здесь (с точки зрения семантики/лексического наполнения)  используется модель предложения **из двух компонентов**:  субъект и осложненный предикат (связанное словосочетание), в состав которого входит определение.

Именно такая модель является **информативной**, в отличие от первой модели. Это объясняется тем, что слово "понятие" имеет **отвлеченное значение.**

**ПОНЯТИЕ,** -я; ср. 1. Мысль, отражающая существенные свойства и необходимые признаки предмета или явления. П. времени. П. качества. П. треугольника. Понятия науки. Отражение понятий в значениях слов.

**[О синтаксически неделимых (связанных) словосочетаниях](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)**, стр. 6 — 9.

Синтаксическая неделимость большинства словосочетаний
объясняется **семантической недостаточностью их главного слова.**

Все синтаксически неделимые словосочетания можно сгруппировать по обобщенному значению или функции их главных и
зависимых слов.

8. Словосочетания, в роли главного слова которых употребляются **существительные** человек, люди, мужчина, женщина, вещь,
   дело, занятие, вопрос, место, время и др. Эти существительные не
   могут самостоятельно (без распространителя) выполнять в предложении синтаксическую функцию сказуемого или обособленного приложения, так как **в их содержании (весьма отвлеченном)**
   отсутствует характеризующая предмет или действие **информация.**

Comment: Именно так! Проводя синтаксический анализ, надо исходить из того, что теория синтаксиса не стоит на месте. Она постоянно обогащается новыми теориями и подходами, за которыми надо следить, чтобы оставаться в теме. В любом случае к решению вопроса надо подходить комплексно и разносторонне, а не цепляться по привычке за консервативные взгляды экспертов прошлого. Ведь рано или поздно приходится согласиться с тем, что Земля вертится.

Comment: Да, синтаксис  –  быстро развивающаяся   наука,  Не все там является общепринятым, поэтому интересно сравнивать разные точки зрения лингвистов.  А еще интересно все это использовать в практике письма. Как вы на это смотрите?)   Есть ли у вас желание обсуждать на форуме практические вопросы по теме?  Хотелось бв вас послушать.

Comment: Я с удовольствием подключусь к практическому синтаксису, однако, боюсь, что моих теоретических знаний будет недостаточно для полноценного участия в сообществе. Тем не менее практика письма меня очень интересует.)

Comment: Смелость города берет)  Поверьте мне, работа на форуме даст вам очень много.  Я здесь уже почти 8 лет, и у меня изначально были какие-то чисто теоретически знания. Но сейчас  они уже другого качества: очень многие темы я лучше стала понимать, уточнила для себя многие вопросы. Все дело в  том, что мы часто решаем нестандартные задачи, вот где приходится думать)  А критика не всегда приятна, но всегда полезна.

Comment: я здесь недавно, но уже понял, что комментарии очень скоро закрывают, как только они перестают быть по теме.)  Таким образом как это происходит? Вы создаёте отдельные темы или это какая-то комната в чате?

Comment: Давайте я её лучше вам на почту отправлю, она экслюзивна.)

Comment: Отправил! Буду рад, если что-нибудь окажется вам полезным.

Comment: Very grateful))