# Он хороший человек, добрый. Уточнение или однородные отношения?

Tags: синтаксис, однородные-члены, словосочетания, уточнения

Вопрос был задан **на Лингвофоруме** и показался мне интересным. Участники не пришли к единому мнению, у каждого было свое обоснование.

Вопрос интересен тем, что он связан  с известным сочетанием ***«хороший человек»***, которое многие считают **несвободным сочетанием**. Такие сочетания разбираются как **единый член** предложения. **Как разбирается** это сочетание в предложенных вариантах (свободное или несвободное)?

На этот вопрос ссылается [в своем ответе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474918/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83) @ Ajgy:

https://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=58268.0 **[Форум. Ответы от разбирающихся в вопросе людей]**

Хотелось бы узнать вашу точку зрения: кто из отвечающих прав. Также можно предложить свой вариант ответа.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

Обсуждение темы **состава сказуемого**, в том числе для сочетания "***хороший человек***":

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463655/Как-назвать-такое-сказуемое](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463655/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5)
*Ну а какое сказуемое Вы видите тогда в таком, к примеру, предложении: "Он — хороший человек"? Напомню, что Кустова, на которую Вы часто ссылаетесь, сказуемым здесь считает всё сочетание "хороший человек".*

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463807/Как-определить-именную-часть-сказуемого-со-словом-человек](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463807/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA)

Comment: я соглашусь с уточнением слова "хорошо": он хороший человек, потому что добрый.

Comment: Я тоже, но надо доказать. Там же оппонент доказательств требует. Вы с ним "поговорите", докажите, что он неправ. Кстати, каждый из них уверен в своей правоте.

Comment: 2013 год там, он жив еще)?

Comment: А вы задайте им интересный вопрос, он и объявится.  У них мало новых тем по русскому языку.

Comment: Можно я немного ереси добавлю?

Comment: Февраль 2022 года, участник на месте, тема интересная   https://lingvoforum.net/index.php/topic,106533.0.html А тема "с хорошим человеком" тоже отрыта, можно написать ответ. Надо их взбодрить. Ереси побольше, ереси!

Comment: Он хороший добрый кот и мышей ловит. Хороший добрый - это сказуемое ли? Сказуемое вроде бы ловит, но проблема в том, что главное слово не "ловит", а предикация мышей. Он хороший добрый кот и быстро бегает. Тут это даже заметнее. А теперь посмотрите как выглядит непредикативное предложение подлежащее-сказуемое: кот бегает в доме. Попробуем сделать непредикативное, но предложение с обстоятельством из первого: он хороший добрый кот, в доме, - и вдруг обстоятельство обособляется. Почему? Потому что "хороший добрый и кот" - вовсе не сказуемое, а структура близкая к обстоятельству, но не совсем оно.

Comment: Потому что обстоятельство свободно перемещения: в доме кот бегает, кот в доме бегает и тп. А вот: "он кот хороший, добрый" - сразу начинаются запятые, потому что нарушается прямой порядок слов. Для предикации важен порядок слов.  Хорошо, делай; хорошо делай! или минимум утвердительная интонация "хорошо делай."; делай - хорошо. или акцент на хорошо - делай хорошо! Ну и тд. предикации требуют интонационного смещения с глагола, на другие слова. В то время как глагол-сказуемое не требует каких-то дополнительных интонаций или синтаксиса.

Comment: Он  кот и мышей ловит. Кот (какой?) хороший и добрый. Он – подлежащее, кот и ловит – однородные сказуемые, все корректно. Это же грамматика, форма, а не семантика.  Синтаксис предлагает нам  разрешенные грамматические модели, и надо работать с ними. А если все перемешать (форму и семантику), то ничего и никому не докажешь, вас просто не поймут. Существующий грамматический язык приходится принимать как он есть и разговаривать на нем, другого варианта у нас нет.

Comment: Он кот. Он - кот и мышей ловит. Он пёс, но мышей ловит. Пёс он, и мышей не ловит.

Comment: Без разницы. Однородные сказуемые можно связывать любыми сочинительными союзами, позиция подлежащего и сказуемого свободная (он пес или пес он).

Comment: Нене, "он кот" это не сказуемое, как  "он  человек" - это не предикации и не сказуемые, это сложные подлежащие.

Comment: Тогда напишите через дефис эти сложные подлежащие, надо же это обозначить на письме.

Comment: Sharon нет, зачем, через дефис пишутся равноправные слова, а сложное подлежащее это слова связанные, но не равнозначные.

Comment: Ну вот сложносоставное наименование "вопросы-ответы" пишется через дефис. Сложные подлежащие? В русской грамматике нет такого понятия. Вы используете терминологию общего языкознания, а для каждого языка существует своя адаптированная грамматика.

Comment: Ну например: коб Бориска выбежал за ворота. Кот Бориска - сложное подлежащее. Тут я увидел змею анаконду - хотя это даже не подлежащее, но вот такое составное слово, не обязательно через дефис, дефис предполагает логику, а тут логики нет, чисто формальное деление, таксономия, родовые слова и тп. Часть таких слов может согласовываться - водитель автомобиля, а часть нет - жук плавунец, но через дефис такие слова не пишутся. С другой стороны если будет реверс плавунец - жук, то нужно ставить тире. С согласованными вероятно можно оставить и без тире,"автомобиля водитель",хотя фраза звучит странно

Comment: Но из-за согласования нет смысла указывать какое слово является к какому родовым, что ли. Водитель - родовое, автомобиль - частный случай. Так вот, "он-хороший человек" - это тоже перевернутая конструкция, прямая звучит как хороший он человек или хороший человек он, тут нет никаких сказуемых, а есть предикативный признак утверждающий родовую таксономию.

Answer (score 0):

**Вместо вступления**. *Неинтересные у меня вопросы, никто на них не отвечает. А что такое интерес? Когда все просто — неинтересно, когда все сложно — неинтересно тоже.  Надо что-то среднее? Но этого недостаточно: тема должна быть актуальной, сиюминутной, востребованной.  Интересы аудитории капризны и непостоянны: только что был интересно, а теперь — нет. Общее внимание переключилось на новую тему.*

***Он хороший человек, добрый.*** Уточнение или однородные отношения?

Предположим, что это **однородные отношения**. Однородные члены должны независимо друг от друга  относиться  к подлежащему: *Он хороший человек, добрый человек.* Но лучше записать так: *Он хороший и добрый человек.* Здесь два определения перед сущ. «человек». Но у нас-то другая запись, и это больше похоже  на пояснение/уточнение (почему хороший).

Тогда **это уточнение/пояснение?** Первый участник дает на это ссылку  http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm  (параграф 92, п. 5). Второй участник возражает: С чего вы решили, что обособленное?  Вольная трактовка. Но первый пишет: Я остаюсь при своем мнении.

**Вот и вся дискуссия.** А если использовать очень распространенное мнение о том, что *хороший человек* — это **несвободное сочетание**. Тогда мы видим, что здесь обозначены однородные отношения между сочетанием «хороший человек» и прилагательным «добрый». В этом случае второй участник прав, а у первого — вольная трактовка.

**ВЫВОД**
Тогда пусть он и будет прав, это **однородные отношения.** И это мой ответ тоже.  Но с условием: ***хороший человек***  —  это несвободное сочетание.

Comment: Я  согласен, здесь нет уточнения, пояснения. Здесь однородные отношения.